# Coming from JSCS to ESLint: missing rules

Tags: javascript, eslint

We have decided to switch over from JSCS to ESLint as it allows more checks for other things. I've managed to convert most of the rules, but two of them I am unable to match with ESLint ruleset. So before I dig into AST and trying to write it on my own, I would like to ask if these aren't already in there.

```
{
    // nothing similar to this seems available
    "requireBlocksOnNewline": 2,
    // there is only rule for after spaces - space-after-keywords
    "requireSpaceBeforeKeywords": ["else", "while", "catch"]
}
```

http://jscs.info/rule/requireBlocksOnNewline.html
http://jscs.info/rule/requireSpaceBeforeKeywords.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`requireBlockOnNewline` can be mimicked with `brace-style: [2, "1tbs"]`
`requireSpaceBeforeKeywords` does not exist, but wouldn't be too hard to create.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. First rule is different too, because we care about newlines only if there is more than 2 statements. The `brace-style` screams for the one statement.

Comment: `brace-style` has an option `allowSingleLine` that might help with that, but it's mostly about not needing braces around single line blocks, not linebreaks